# download a pdf file from a server doesn't work using itextSharp

Tags: pdf, download, itext

i've created a function that creates a pdf file and insert it into a doc file, problem is i can't download it from that directory, here is my code:

```
    private void FillForm(Dictionary<string, string> dic)
    {

        var pdfTemplate = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ress/NOUVELLE_VERSION_GENE_15_04_2014.pdf"); //_pdfTemplet;

        var newFile = _newFileName + "_" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf";

         _gNewFile = newFile.ToString();

        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfTemplate));

        var pfileStream = new FileStream(string.Format(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ress/") + "{0}", newFile), FileMode.Create);

        var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pfileStream);
        var pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

        foreach (var entry in dic)
        {
            pdfFormFields.SetField(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
        pdfStamper.JavaScript = "this.print(true);\r";
        pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
        pdfReader.Close();
        pdfStamper.Close();
        UPContract.Update();
        pfileStream.Close();
        pdf.FilePath = string.Format("../Ress/{0}", Path.GetFileName(_gNewFile));

        Response.Clear();
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(string.Format(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ress/") + "{0}", _gNewFile));
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "fiche abonnement_" + _gNewFile + ".pdf");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

}

if anyone cant give me a tip ! thank you.

Comment: Why are you creating the file on the file system? Why aren't you creating it in memory? Do you need the file to be on the file system?

Comment: yes i need it in the server so the client can download it, but if you can show me how to create it in memory i'll be very thankful.

Comment: So you don't need it on the server's file system for the client to download it. It's sufficient to create it in memory. Please don't confuse people by answering in riddles. Be more accurate!

Comment: ok @BrunoLowagie, can you help me with it?

Comment: Is it that urgent?

Comment: yes if it's possible.thank you.

Comment: OK, I'm working on an answer. I hope you pay the invoice for using iTextSharp as fast as I provide my answer ;-)

Comment: hh no problem ! thak you @BrunoLowagie :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the file on the file system, you can create it in memory. This is done using a `MemoryStream`. I took your code, copy/pasted it and adapted it so that the `FileStream` is replaced by a `MemoryStream`.

I couldn't test your code, so you may need to tweak it here and there, but you'll get the idea of what you should try to achieve:

```
var pdfTemplate = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("...");
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfTemplate));
var output = new MemoryStream();
var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, output);
var pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
foreach (var entry in dic)
{
    pdfFormFields.SetField(entry.Key, entry.Value);
}
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
pdfStamper.JavaScript = "this.print(true);\r";
pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
pdfStamper.Close();
pdfReader.Close();
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=fiche abonnement_" + _gNewFile + ".pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray()); 
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: it didn't work my friend, no reaction when im hitting the validation button !

Comment: What is the validation button?

Comment: i'll explain the concept, i have a form,im filling up the information(name, email...) when i hit the validation button im calling this function to use a pdf template to write the information into it and then download it. that's all, when i was using my past code, it's creates the pdf file into a specific directory, but no download is working, now when i replaced my code with your modifications , i can see the loading page but after it ends got nothing to show up !

Comment: Debug your code. Chances are that your browser isn't configured correctly. You need to test this on different browsers using different PDF viewers.

Comment: i've tried over debuging and changing browser.. same thing !